# How to design an algorithm to (almost) always win in the Kayles game (Normal Play Convention)

Tags: algorithm

I have encountered an algorithm designing problem **which is designing an algorithm to (almost) always win in the Kayles game**, i.e., the goal is to always win if one goes first and have the best chance to win if one goes second. The rule of the game is, there is a line of pins, each pin has an index, two players take turns to knock them down, and a player can knock down **one or two** pins for each turn, if there are two pins to be knocked down, they have to be adjacent to each other, for example, if there are 1, 2, 3, 4 four pins, 2 and 3 are down, then 1 and 4 are **not** adjacent to each other, but 1 and 2, 2 and 3, etc.. **The player who knocks down the last pin(s) wins**.

The hints of the problem are represents the pins via an array of boolean, and the inputs may include the index or indices of the opponent's last move.

I have done some online research about this game, but so far I only know that the player who goes first can always win, by removing the middle pin(s), dividing the pins into two groups, then imitate the opponent's move in another group. I also know that if one is going second, the best strategy is roughly creating an even number of groups of pins, such as `1101101110111`, which has two pairs of groups, then imitate the opponent's move in one of the pair of groups. But I don't really sure how to design an algorithm from here.

Thanks for reading to here!

Comment: There is a fairly complete answer to this at http://www.numericana.com/answer/games.htm#kayles which shows how to reduce any Kayles pile to an equivalent Nim pile, and then you use the method of analysis of Nim to find the best strategy.  https://plus.maths.org/content/play-win-nim  is an alternate take on Nim that may be more accessible if you're not familiar with it.

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks for your reply and your critics, I edited the question and will try to come up with a better question next time. I was (and still am) unsure about how to design this algorithm in the first place. I was trying to code it in Java but the algorithm I first came up was far from correct, tested with some simple cases.

Comment: @btilly Thanks, I will look into them right now.